Regex: Capture only matching alternative in Ruby
I am cracking my head open with this:
I am building a simple password generator which uses a pattern created by the user. The pattern contains the letters a-f which stand for 6 character groups:

So, if the user enters ababcd, he/she will get something like abce1!
The pattern Ababababababccd would generate something like Robuxejiqu23#.
Since Ababababababccd seems hardly readable I want to give the possibility to abbreviate this with repetitions:
Ababababababccd could be written as Ab(ab){5}ccd or even Ab(ab){5}c{2}d(which would be dumb, but for completeness).
The [ab] comes into play if want to have either a character from group a or group b.
I have "built" a suitable Regex expression which captures the repetitions in following combinations:

single character repetition like a{3} would become aaa
group repetition (ab){2}would become abab
XOR-group repetition [ab]{2} becomes either ab or aa or ba etc.
combinations of 2 and 3: (a[bc]d){n}

The regex expression I built so far finds all the cases above:
/(?:(\[[abcdef]+\])|\(([\[\]abcdef]+)\)|([abcdef]))\{(\d+)\}/i
My working Ruby code looks like this, but it'd like find a more elegant solution:
# class
REPETITION = /(?:(\[[abcdef]+\])|\(([\[\]abcdef]+)\)|([abcdef]))\{(\d+)\}/i
GROUPS = /\[([abcdefxyz]+)\]/i;

# method generate
pattern = params[:pattern]
group = {
  'A' => params[:group_a].upcase,
  'a' => params[:group_a],
  'B' => params[:group_b].upcase,
  'b' => params[:group_b],
  'C' => params[:group_c].upcase,
  'c' => params[:group_c],
  'D' => params[:group_d].upcase,
  'd' => params[:group_d],
  'E' => params[:group_e].upcase,
  'e' => params[:group_e],
  'F' => params[:group_f].upcase,
  'f' => params[:group_f]
}

# Evaluate repetitions: ...{n}
if pattern =~ REPETITION
  pattern.gsub!(REPETITION) do
    match = $1 != nil ? $1 : $2 != nil ? $2 : $3
    count=$4.to_i
    expanded=""
    count.times do
      expanded+=match
    end
    expanded
  end
end

# Evaluate character groups [...]
if pattern =~ GROUPS
  pattern.gsub!(GROUPS) do
    $1[rand($1.length)]
  end
end

# Evaluate the final pattern (repetitions and []-groups processed)
password=""
pattern.each_char do |c|
  password+=group[c][rand(group[c].length)]
end
@password=password;

My idea is to find all occurences and replace the repetitions with the expanded repetitions so that Ab(ab){5}ccd becomes Ababababababccd which I process afterwards.
My assumption is that .gsub handles each occurences individually and and I can replace each match with its suitable pattern and count. If gsub tries to replace all of them at once it will be the wrong method.
For me it's not relevant which of the groups in (?:a|b|c){count} matches, but the match should be returned as $1 and the count as $2.
The above regex leads to the matches $1, $2, $3 and $4. $4 is always my repetition count. But then I have to find out which $1 .. $3 is not nil and use it to expand. I could to the "cheap" case and if through the cases but I want to have an elegant solution.
In regex101 I got it to work with (?| but Ruby does not understand that.
I hope it is clear what I want!?
In Typescript and C# I got it working and now I want it to work in Ruby... :-)

"I hope it is clear what I want!?" – not quite. Are you trying to build a regular expression to match other regular expressions?

Yeah in a way... I used Keepass' password generator pattern as inspiration.

Are you sure you want to create passwords based on patterns ? Seems like a bad idea

@Stefan I just edited my question an hope it's more clear now. :-)

@Thomas Yeah you are not wrong but I often create passwords for users that should be pronouncable and there comes my pattern into play. :-)

In "my system" I could write [abcdef]{16} and would have a totally random password.

@engineersmnky I changed the example accordingly, thanks :-)

@engineersmnky I have read your suggestion, but I found it counter intuitive as a Ruby beginner. It's elegant - no question - but I fear if I look at it at a later point in time I'll go "WTF!?"

Here is what I came up with to handle the provided cases.
REPETITION = /(\[[abcdef]+\]|\([\[\]abcdef]+\)|[abcdef])(?:\{(\d+)\})?/i

GROUPS = {
  'a' => 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz',
  'b' => 'aeiou',
  'c' => '0123456789',
  'd' => '!$%&/()=?*+#_.,:;_'
}.then {|h| h.merge(h.map {|k,v| [k.upcase,v.upcase]}.to_h)}

def expand(str)
  str.scan(REPETITION).map do |group, count|
    sub_pattern = group.start_with?('(') ? group[/(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))/, 1] : group
    count ? sub_pattern * count.to_i : sub_pattern
  end.join.gsub(/\[.*?\]/) {|match| match[1..-2].chars.shuffle.first}
end 

def generate(str, groups=GROUPS)
  expanded = expand(str)
  puts "Expansion: #{expanded}"
  expanded.each_char.sum(""){|c| groups[c][rand(groups[c].length)]}
end 

Example output:
patterns = ['(ab){2}','a{3}','[ab]{2}','(a[bc]d){16}','Ab(ab){5}ccd','Ab(ab){5}c{2}d']

patterns.each do |pattern|
  puts "-------Pattern: #{pattern}-------"
  puts "Generated: #{generate(pattern)}"
end

# -------Pattern: (ab){2}-------
# Expansion: abab
# Generated: niha
# -------Pattern: a{3}-------
# Expansion: aaa
# Generated: svh
# -------Pattern: [ab]{2}-------
# Expansion: ba
# Generated: ak
# -------Pattern: (a[bc]d){16}-------
# Expansion: abdacdabdabdabdabdabdacdacdacdacdabdabdacdabdabd
# Generated: lu+s5$cu%ye#re+mo%qu)s4?c1*h8(l5!ja*zu?g9_lu/ze!
# -------Pattern: Ab(ab){5}ccd-------
# Expansion: Ababababababccd
# Generated: Meqonicovala75!
# -------Pattern: Ab(ab){5}c{2}d-------
# Expansion: Ababababababccd
# Generated: Pezotuwegona98#

We match the repetitions, expand them by the count, and then replace the XORs to expand the full pattern.
Then we simply lookup each character from the GROUPS hash and select a random element.
Note: this does not handle other cases such as:

Group inside an XOR Ab[a(bc)d]{12}
Repetition inside a group which is then replicated Ab(ab{5}){4}
Likely many more


Wow, that's impressive! It's also a lot to swallow but I will "decode" it and change my code accordingly. Thanks a lot for your efforts!!!

Okay, while the GROUPS.then part feels a bit like showing off ;) (no offense meant!) the expand method is really smart! I like the functional approach. Thanks again!

@ElHippo no offense taken you asked for elegance, which to me equates to minimalism where possible and that implementation DRYs it up a bit. Thanks for posting a true ruby question, I certainly prefer that over all the rails magic.

The question was born in a Rails context to be honest... I can relate to your understanding of elegance being minimalistic, but there is a thin line between code being elegant and cryptic. So for me elegant means using the language the code is written in to express as much as possible in as few code as possible (as you said) while maintaining simplicity and readability. :-)

I ended up using this solution:
REPETITION = /(\[[abcdef]+\]|\([\[\]abcdef]+\)|[abcdef])(?:\{(\d+)\})?/i

pattern = params[:pattern]
group = {
  'A' => params[:group_a].upcase,
  'a' => params[:group_a],
  'B' => params[:group_b].upcase,
  'b' => params[:group_b],
  'C' => params[:group_c].upcase,
  'c' => params[:group_c],
  'D' => params[:group_d].upcase,
  'd' => params[:group_d],
  'E' => params[:group_e].upcase,
  'e' => params[:group_e],
  'F' => params[:group_f].upcase,
  'f' => params[:group_f]
}

password = pattern.scan(REPETITION).map do |p, c|
  # Evaluate repetitions: ...{n}
  s = p.start_with?('(') ? p[1..-2] : p
  c ? [s] * c.to_i : [s]
end.flatten.map do |m|
  # Evaluate character groups [...]
  m.start_with?('[') ? m[1..-2].chars.sample : m
end.join.chars.map do |e|
  # Evaluate the final pattern (repetitions and []-groups processed)
  group[e][rand(group[e].length)]
end.join

@password = password

It incorporates the magic from @engineersmnky and makes the single steps a bit clearer - for me at least.
